# String calculator in wpf, fill textboxes in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, calculator

So I'm currently working on my stringbased Calculator (academic excercise, I'm still learning), and I put a lot of logic in the Code Behind of the view. Now my task is to transfer that logic into the viewmodel. I'm stuck right now, I created Properties for the 2 textboxes that I have, and all I want is for the digits/operators I click on to be added to the textbox string, at least for now, my Calculator Engine will do the rest. But I can't seem to fill the textboxes. They should start out with "0", and every button I click needs to add the corresponding digit to the textboxes, but right now it just replaces the current one, or adds it, but only combined with the "0". Hope I'm not too vague, and it's not too much code, I'm still learning.
When debugging I see that the value of LowerTextBox, after "LowerTextBox = character", where character is "8" for example, LowerTextBox gets "08", why is that?

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _lastButtonEqual;
    public ICommand StandardButtonCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand DigitsOnlyCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        StandardButtonCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(Button_Click);

        DigitsOnlyCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(OnlyDigitsInTextBox);
    }

    private string _upperTextBox;

    public string UpperTextBox
    {
        get { return _upperTextBox = "0"; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _upperTextBox) return;
            _upperTextBox += value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _lowerTextBox;

    public string LowerTextBox
    {
        get { return _lowerTextBox = "0"; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _lowerTextBox) return;
            _lowerTextBox += value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void OnlyDigitsInTextBox(string character)
    {
        if (UpperTextBox.EndsWith("+") || UpperTextBox.EndsWith("-") || UpperTextBox.EndsWith("/") ||
            UpperTextBox.EndsWith("*") || LowerTextBox == "0" || _lastButtonEqual)
        {
            LowerTextBox = character;
        }
        else
        {
            LowerTextBox += character;
        }

        if (UpperTextBox == "0")
        {
            UpperTextBox = character;
        }
        else
        {
            UpperTextBox = UpperTextBox + character;
        }

        _lastButtonEqual = false;
    }

    private void Button_Click(string digit)
    {
        OnlyDigitsInTextBox(digit);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the setter of your `LowerTextBox` you append the value you are setting (`_lowerTextBox += value`). Hence, the value gets appended instead of replaced.

Comment: I changed that at some point because I thought it might make sense. I changed it back like you said, but now nothing happens when I click a button, the LowerTextBox, despite the line "LowerTextBox = character;" keeps "0" as a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your Properties getter and setter to this.

```
private string _lowerTextBox = "0";

    public string LowerTextBox
    {
        get { return _lowerTextBox; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _lowerTextBox) return;
            _lowerTextBox = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that works, and it makes a lot of sense too, should have seen that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your Getters look like this

```
get { return _lowerTextBox = "0"; }
```

That will essentially assign the value "0" and then return the just assigned value "0".

They should look like this

```
get { return _lowerTextBox; }
```

If you want to set an initial value, do it like this

```
private string _lowerTextBox = "0";
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now, should have seen that this makes much more sense.